# RegEx to match two alternatives but nothing else

Tags: regex

I need to capture either

```
\d+\.\d+
```

or

```
\d+
```

but nothing else.

**For instance**, "0.02", "1" and "0.50" should match positively. I noticed that I cannot simply use something like

```
[\d+\.\d+|\d+]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can do either:

```
(\d+|\d+\.\d+)
```

or

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

but that creates a second capturing group. The more sophisticated version is:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

That's called a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

By the way [Regular Expression Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a superb site for regular expression tutorials and information.

Comment: http://www.regexbuddy.com/ is a nice tool if you use a lot of regular expressions - it's not free, though.

Answer (score 0):

Or `\d+(\.\d+)?` if you find that easier to read :)